# Faster way to select rows and apply function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, python-itertools

I am looking to calculate distance between current and next end point in the data below. A single key can have multiple end points (x,y).

I am looking for a faster solution to the above problem than what I have as it is taking many hours to execute.

[image: check the formula for calculate distance bewteen 2 endpoints]

#### Data

```py
Key  x     y

1   87.4375 28.921875
1   97.4375 23.921875
1   97.4375 23.921875
1   97.4375 23.921875
1   97.4375 23.921875
2   86.4375 24.921875
2   85.4375 24.921875
2   93.4375 29.921875
2   86.4375 24.921875
2   85.4375 24.921875
2   93.4375 29.921875
```

#### What I have tried:

#### Solution 1

```
new_df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['key', 'distance'])
for key in orig_df.key.values:
    
    x2 = orig_df.loc[orig_df.key== key ,'x'].shift(-1)
    y2 = orig_df.loc[orig_df.key== key ,'y'].shift(-1)
    x1 = orig_df.loc[orig_df.key== key ,'x']
    y1 = orig_df.loc[orig_df.key== key ,'y']
    distance = cal_distance(x2,y2,x1,y1)
    new_df.append({'key': key, 'distance': distance}, ignore_index=True)

def cal_distance(x2,y2,x1,y1):
    return abs(np.sqrt( np.square(x2 - x1) + np.square(y2 - y1))).sum()
```

There are lots of rows and its taking few hours to execute the above code.

#### Solution 2(Didn't work)

```
orig_df.groupby('key').pipe(cal_distance(orig_df.x.shift(-1),orig_df.y.shift(-1),orig_df.x,orig_df.y))
```

I tried to group based on key.

Any help much appreciated.

#### Expected output

```
    key distance
0   1   11.18034
1   2   29.470288
```

Comment: Please don't include information in images, write it in the post itself. It would also be appreciated if you could share that data in a format that is easier to use, like CSV, or even just the output of `to_dict()`. Some general advice, for now: Don't use `.values`. Don't use explicit loops. Don't append to a DataFrame. No wonder it takes hours.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: What's a key? What's an end point?

Comment: For `Key =2`, there are three points. For which of these 3 points you want to calculate distance?

Comment: @Alexander Was your _key is the first column in the dataframe._ in response to me?

Comment: OP, I can't even get your code to work, so there's currently no way for us to understand exactly what you want. As an aside, where are you getting your input from?

Comment: @Alexander That wasn't my question.

Comment: @Alexander Wait is _The are six pair of points for key=2_ also a response to my comment?

Comment: [ask]  Post the question and respond to feedback

After you post, leave the question open in your browser for a bit, and see if anyone comments. If you missed an obvious piece of information, be ready to respond by editing your question to include it. If someone posts an answer, be ready to try it out and provide feedback!

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks for the feed back on using explicit loops and using stack overflow.

Comment: @Alexander I have added the output now.My bad

Comment: @ShreeshaKumarBhat Can you clarify what exactly it is you’re trying to do?

Comment: @ShreeshaKumarBhat Why did you accept my answer? Is the “expected output” above no longer correct?

Comment: I accepted because it has helped to solve the question .Now the execution time has reduced to 9 minutes

Comment: @ShreeshaKumarBhat Alright, so you do still want those two output values. I will edit my post in a bit.

Comment: @ShreeshaKumarBhat Can you explain what you’re trying to do? You never did, the description of the problem is still ambiguous and unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As predicted, the actual desired behaviour was slightly different than what I had guessed. I will be updating my answer to reflect that, it should be a small tweak.

Where to begin. Your code is extremely unidiomatic. I'm quite certain that idiomatic Pandas code would not take hours to produce a result. It isn't even clear why you're using Pandas in the first place. As you will see in my solution below, the use of Pandas makes things far more awkward and clunky than they should be.

Of course, this may not be the desired result, since the question is ambiguous and unclear.

```py
from io import StringIO

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

raw_str = \
    '''
    key  x     y

    1   87.4375 28.921875
    1   97.4375 23.921875
    1   97.4375 23.921875
    1   97.4375 23.921875
    1   97.4375 23.921875
    2   86.4375 24.921875
    2   85.4375 24.921875
    2   93.4375 29.921875
    2   86.4375 24.921875
    2   85.4375 24.921875
    2   93.4375 29.921875
    '''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(raw_str), delim_whitespace=True)

rows_list = []

for k, v in df.groupby('key'):
    coords = v[['x', 'y']].to_numpy()
    coords_shifted = np.roll(coords, shift=-1, axis=0)
    dist = np.linalg.norm(coords[:-1] - coords_shifted[:-1], axis=1).sum()
    rows_list.append((k, dist))

res_df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows_list, columns=['key', 'distance'])

print(res_df)
```

`res_df`:

```
   key   distance
0    1  11.180340
1    2  29.470288
```

Comment: But this solution gives the incorrect result.  `res_df.groupby('key').sum()` does not result in the expected output.

Comment: @Alexander I am also confused. Although I will be updating my solution, I wish OP told us how they ended up using this.

Comment: @Alexander Oh and as for the exact reason why the output is different, it’s because I used `numpy.roll()` instead of `shift()`.

Comment: I had changed a line of code `dists = np.linalg.norm(coords[:-1] - coords_shifted[:-1], axis=1)` to not calculate the rolling distance between last and first end points for each key

Comment: @ShreeshaKumarBhat Can you explain what you’re doing, what this is for?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile For example: `4     1  11.180340` in res def is the distance between points last co-ordinate of key1(97.4375,23.921875) and 1st cordinate of key1(87.4375,28.921875). I don't want to include this distance

Comment: @ShreeshaKumarBhat What I meant is what is this program **for**?! What is it doing. You’re talking about keys and points without explaining what any of these actually are.

Comment: @ShreeshaKumarBhat I edited the program, the output is now the same as the desired output. I would still appreciate some clarity on the questions I have asked, including the confusing choice of Pandas over NumPy, as well as how you're getting the data in the first place.

Comment: @Alexander Updated, it should now produce the correct result!

Comment: @Alexander Coming back to this post made me realize I should get rid of that loop and create a function for use with `apply()/map()`...

Comment: With some slight modifications, my pure Pandas solution is running almost 30% faster than your Numpy solution on 1m rows of sample data.

Comment: @Alexander Is that from the most recent changes you made?

Comment: @Alexander Alright, nicely done! I’ll take a look, and tweak my solution, tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Random data (1m rows, 1000 keys)

np.random.seed(0)

rows = 1_000_000
keys = 1000
keys = np.random.randint(low=1, high=keys, size=rows)
x = np.random.rand(rows) * 360
y = np.random.rand(rows) * 360
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': keys, 'x': x, 'y': y})
```

**Solution**

This calculates the distance between subsequent points in each key based group, and then aggregates the total distance for each key.  Based on the sample data with 1 million rows above, this takes about 0.8 seconds to run.

```
df.sort_values('key', kind='mergesort', inplace=True)  # `mergesort` is the only stable algorithm.
distances = (
    df
    .apply(lambda s: s.diff().pow(2)).sum(axis=1).pow(0.5)  # Calculate distances b/w endpoints.
    .groupby(df['key'])
    .apply(lambda s: s.iloc[1:].sum())  # Sum the distances between endpoints by key.
)

>>> distances.head()
key
1    198431.901333
2    192694.829351
3    176125.208567
4    186942.057497
5    182029.077809
dtype: float64
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
Using the OP's original dataframe, the solution above results in the expected output:

```
>>> distances
key
1    11.180340
2    29.470288
dtype: float64
```

**Comments on your code**

Looking at your code in **Solution 1**, you are looping through _all_the key values (`for key in orig_df.key.values:`). That would be 11 loops in the sample data above.  For each loop, you then use `.loc` to find the values for that key.  Note that each `.loc` operation returns the same *group* based on the key, not the row.

Assuming that `key=2`, your data looks like this:

```
         x1       x2         y1         y2
5   86.4375  85.4375  24.921875  24.921875
6   85.4375  93.4375  24.921875  29.921875
7   93.4375  86.4375  29.921875  24.921875
8   86.4375  85.4375  24.921875  24.921875
9   85.4375  93.4375  24.921875  29.921875
10  93.4375      NaN  29.921875        NaN
```

So the output of  `np.sqrt( np.square(x1 - x2) + np.square(y1 - y2))` is this:

```
5     1.000000
6     9.433981
7     8.602325
8     1.000000
9     9.433981
10         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Where you then **incorrectly** sum the column.  You need to sum each row specifying the axis (`.sum(axis=1)`.  Also, I'm not sure if your shift is in the right direction, but it depends how your original data is structured. In the end, it probably doesn't matter but it depends on how you intend to use the results.

As a minor point, there is no need to take the absolute value in your function, as the sum of two squared values will always be non-negative, and thus so will the sum's square root.

Comment: According to sample data provided by OP only two values(unique keys) should be there in output.

Comment: @shaikmoeed How do you know that?

Comment: @shaikmoeed Again, I don't think there is any real indication of that.

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the OP question. From OP *I am looking to calculate distance between current and next end point in the data below. A single key can have multiple end points (x,y).* and `groupby` code in OP makes me to go for 1st and 2nd value of each group.

Comment: @Alexander OP's neither solution is working. And I strongly believe that there are duplicate data points for each group, which is why OP said *current and next end point*

Comment: @Alexander Nice solution, but it is still taking hours to execute. Vectorization with numpy solution in accepted answer works well. Execution time reduced to 9 minutes

Comment: @ShreeshaKumarBhat How large is your data? I would think that this solution would be fine performance-wise.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile 2.4 GB after memory reduction of original dataset. I am executing on a kaggle kernel

Comment: @ShreeshaKumarBhat Are you sure you’re performing the correct operation? Can you share that data?